# How will I run sudo visudo command in VM?

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

I tried to run `sudo visudo` command but I'm getting error like "*visudo is not command*".so how can I solve it and edit `/etc/sudoers` file?

Comment: Can yo please edit your question to add the actual error you get? *visudo is not command .so* does not make sense for me (I've never seen such error)

Comment: try `sudo -i` ... then in the new prompt, `visudo`

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the full path for the `visudo` command, i.e. `sudo /usr/sbin/visudo`.

If that works, then probably the `PATH` environment variable for the command launched by `sudo` doesn't currently include `/sbin` and/or `/usr/sbin` for some reason. Since Ubuntu is designed for extensive use of `sudo`, that would be somewhat unexpected; perhaps some earlier customization by you is affecting root's `PATH` setting?

If `sudo /usr/sbin/visudo` does not work, try `sudo apt reinstall sudo`; perhaps the `visudo` binary or some of its dependencies have been damaged somehow?